# As a regular user, how do I revoke QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES granted to an app?

Tags: permissions, android-11

My phone is Android 11. One app asked to scan my installed apps, and I accidentally tapped OK. Now the app no longer asks for this permission.

I believe the granted permission is QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES. I go to App info screen -> Permissions. It only shows a limited number of permissions, such as Contacts, Storage, and Location.

I know Android has [hundreds of permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission). The permissions on the App info screen are definitely incomplete.

How do I revoke QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES?

Also, in case I guess wrong, and my malicious app requested a different permission than QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES, is there a screen showing ALL hundred permissions?

Comment: *"How do I revoke QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES?"* [`QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/Manifest.permission#QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES:kotlin.String) has `normal` protection level. It's not revocable. // *"is there a screen showing ALL hundred permissions?"* You can try my app [Permission Manager X](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX).

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you. Your Permission Manager X works perfectly!